# How to grant access to UserAgent of PrintFriendly?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, printing, user-agent

I use [PrintFriendly](https://www.printfriendly.com/) to convert webpage to PDF. However on some sites the images could not be included.

The FAQ told users to "[grant access to our UserAgent](https://support.printfriendly.com/button/developer-questions/pdf-images-not-included/)". Is this a setting from server side or client side?

If this can be configured by client, how can it be configured?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: No. I emailed PrintFriendly. They said this FAQ applies to publisher of webpages.

Comment: However you can choose PDF printers, but the printed PDF will lost bookmarks.